# How to scrape all the data from a page using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I can not click the button of the days.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://rate.am/en/armenian-dram-exchange-rates/banks/non-cash"
browser.get(url)
from selenium import *
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import*
```

After importing all necessary tools I have tried to write code which will go to the page, click to the historical data and go by dates, but I have problem with clicking on the days buttons

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://rate.am/en/armenian-dram-exchange-rates/banks/non-cash"
browser.get(url)
all_data=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')
all_data.click()
years=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calBorder"]/span/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/select')
for i in range(len(years.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'))):    
    for j in range(12):
        for z in range(31):
            time=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_Content_RB_dtpick1_dpHours"]')
            for x in range(len(time.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'))):
                all_data=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')
                all_data.click()
                sleep(0.3)                
                yearss = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calBorder"]/span/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/select')
                sy = Select(yearss)
                sy.select_by_index(i)
                sleep(0.3)
                months = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calBorder"]/span/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/select')
                sm = Select(months)
                sm.select_by_index(j)
                sleep(0.3)
                days=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calBorder"]/span/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]')
                if 'bgcolor="white"'==None in days:
                    days.click()
                    sleep(0.3)
                times=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_Content_RB_dtpick1_dpHours"]')
                ti=Select(times)
                ti.select_by_index(x)
                sleep(0.3)
                show=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_Content_RB_dtpick1_btnOk"]')
                show.click()
                sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: maybe you can try build url youself , like http://rate.am/en/armenian-dram-exchange-rates/banks/non-cash/2017/06/15/13-15

Comment: I am not allowed to use other links

Comment: You might be interested in knowing that you can avoid the need to use of selenium by making requests like http://rate.am/en/armenian-dram-exchange-rates/banks/non-cash/2015/04/09/20-15. Mind you, in spite of the presence of the 'en' in this url, the page is returned in a non-Roman alphabet (Armenian I assume). Would this do you?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't handled the year but the pattern would be the same. As far as selecting days is concerned I created an xpath that would identify all of the `td` elements and then select those whose text was equal to a given date, namely 23, which was just a random choice on my part.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> url = 'http://rate.am/en/armenian-dram-exchange-rates/banks/non-cash'
>>> browser.get(url)
>>> browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="date-picker"]').click()
>>> browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//select[@name="MonthSelector"]').click()
>>> browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//select[@name="MonthSelector"]/option[1]').click()
>>> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td[@class="calTD"]')
>>> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td[@class="calTD" and text()="23"]')[0].click()
>>> browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="ctl00_Content_RB_dtpick1_btnOk"]').click()
```